# What is the best way to provide hundreds of Google Analytics reports?

Tags: google-analytics, report, analytics, reporting

We have a large site +200k pages which are divided in to two main categories which each include 100-300 sub-categories.

We need to report monthly for each sub-category with same base report. Only way to differentiate categories is to use Page Path.

There's many problems regarding content's of report. Name's should be related to category name, some panels should be name according to category name etc.

There's no way I'm going to create segments for each nor creating report for each segment.

Currently we've got another analytics solution that provides this feature but lacks a lot of other features included in Google Analytics.

We are using content grouping and DataStudio which allows users to just go and select their sub-category but this is facing some resistance. Why? Don't know, maybe they just want that monthly PDF report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially set up a separate View (based on the page URL) for each sub-category. How many sub-category are we talking about?

What data visualization tool are you guys using? (Standard Google Dashboard? Data Studio? Tableau?) There are many ways to potentially automate these reports based on the same template. Please provide more context so we can help you better.